# ion-label with custom full width form control

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

How can I use `ion-label` with a 100% width custom form control?
Currently as soon as I add an `ion-label` to my `ion-item` inside my form, where I am using a custom form control (not `ion-input`) my custom form control field is not visible anymore.

So, what can I change to make the `ion-label` work with a custom form control?

Example code:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Keywords</ion-label>
  <custom-input formControlName="content"></custom-input>
</ion-item>
```

I also tried this:

```
<!-- Item with a label and content -->
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>
      Item Label
    </ion-label>
    <div item-content>
      Item Content will be next to the label (not full width)
      <custom-input formControlName="content" item-end></custom-input>
    </div>
  </ion-item>
```

However this does ends up only taking a fraction of the width of my page.

With `item-end`:
[image]

With `item-content`:
[image]

I want the `custom-input` to be 100% width (e.g. text editor)

## Solution

Inspired by the double item idea from @Sampath:

```
<ion-item no-lines>
  <ion-label>Content</ion-label>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <custom-input formControlName="content"></custom-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Can you show your current `code`?

Comment: @Sampath I added some sample code snipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `item-end` `attribute` like below.

> That's because ion-item component has predefined set of selectors that
>   can be used to transclude inside that component

[**official Git Repo**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/item/item.ts#L277-L289)

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Keywords</ion-label>
  <custom-input formControlName="content" item-end></custom-input>
</ion-item>
```

If you need to use `full width` then:

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Keywords</ion-label>
 </ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <custom-input formControlName="content" item-start></custom-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: You are right -- this does show up -- however it is not full width (which is what I am looking for). I will also add screenshots to make it clear.

Comment: item-start does also not take up full width.. however the double ion-item does work -- without the item-start and without the `floating` label.

Comment: Hope all are fine now no?

Comment: Yes, thank you @Sampath. :)
I posted my updated solution triggered by your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I tried as follows and working smart, please try and update any other good methods.

```
<ion-row>
   <ion-col size="5">
        <ion-label floating>Content: </ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="7">
        <ion-select formControlName= ...
        </ion-select>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```